# Questions pointing to video recipe (only) should be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/87703/how-to-make-chocolate-to-be-solid) points to a Youtube video recipe.
There is no recipe (not even a part) in the text of the question.

IMO it should be closed (most likely as *Unclear what you're asking*).

Like answers, questions should contain the essential parts, so that they can be understood without requiring us to go to an external source, right?

Answer (score 1):

It's a case by case thing, in my view, and it's always better to edit than to just close, if possible.

Sometimes the details of the recipe are really critical to the question, and sometimes they're not. If we try to make a strict rule about it, we're gonna get it wrong sometimes. We're not doing anyone any favors if we close a question because it linked to a video when it's actually answerable already without watching the video, but yes, we should close if the video details are critical and we can't manage to get them into the question.

This question is kind of a weird example, because it turns out the recipe was for chocolate sauce, so of course it's not solid. There's not much to answer, so the video recipe isn't really much of an issue. Your edit adding the title of the video recipe is enough, though maybe "why isn't this sauce solid?" is close-worthy for other reasons :)